# How to interpret ejabberd crash dumps?

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, crash-dumps

My server keeps getting filled up with ejabberd crash logs every few hours - it seems that the ejabberd server keep crashing and the crash log will fill the server's free space until the server has no more space left (GBs of crash logs). The crash logs start with something like this:

```
=erl_crash_dump:0.1
Tue Feb  4 23:44:02 2014
Slogan: Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,kernel,    {shutdown,{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}})
System version: Erlang R14B04 (erts-5.8.5) [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [rq:2] [async-threads:0] [kernel-poll:false]
Compiled: Fri Dec 16 03:22:15 2011
Taints: 
Atoms: 4574
```

Can anyone see something from the crash log and let me know what's happening?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18641265/720999) I tried to explain to someone how to interpret Erlang crash dumps.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the crash dump is unlikely to tell you very much - it tells you that the kernel application shut down (`{shutdown,{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}`), but it doesn't say why.  In the error log you should find a number of crash reports and error messages that led to the node shutting down.

Crash dumps are much more useful if the node crashes because it runs out of memory.  In that case, you can usually see which process behaved badly.